# Changing Y-scale of a movieclip

Tags: flash, flash-cs5, actionscript-3

I'm trying to change the y-scale or x-scale of a movieclip. I've tried a few tutorials but they're always talking about "elem._yscale".. However it's no longer supported by AS5.

Can somebody please help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need `someDisplayObject.scaleY`. Documentation [here](http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/display/DisplayObject.html#scaleY)!

Answer (score 0):

Exactly like fenomas says you need to use the `scaleX` and `scaleY` setter methods. If you need a specific width or height in pixels you can also use `movieClip.width = 400;`, `movieClip.height = 400;`

You can also combine scaleX and scaleY if you need the same value like `movieClip.scaleX = movieClip.scaleY = 1.5;`